# Linearize and Solve the differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In question 2a)

[image]

I have found the Linearization to be: 
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt} + \frac{1}{g\theta}\frac{\theta^2}{2} = e^{-\frac{t}{2g}}$$

To solve this I found the integrating factor to be $e^{\frac{t}{2g}}$

I found the final answer to be:

$$\theta = te^{-\frac{t}{2g}} + ce^{-\frac{t}{2g}}$$

I am not sure if I used the correct approach here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello! the linearization is correct, the integrating factor and final answer are correct too.